# How to fix a nullable expression can't be used as a condition error

Tags: flutter, dart

The following code gives me an error on the line: "rememberMe = newValue" of:
"A value of type 'bool?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'."

But if I change the declaration of rememberMe to "bool? rememberMe = false;"
I then get an error on the line:
"if (rememberMe) {" of:
"A nullable expression can't be used as a condition."

The bool? also creates an issue with the line: "prefs.setBool('remember', rememberMe);"

```
  bool rememberMe = false;
  ...

  setRemberMeValue() async {
    await _getRememberUser();
    if (rememberMe) {
      usernameController.text = userName;
      passwordController.text = password;
      setState(() {
        rememberMe = rememberMe;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userField = UserTextField(style: style, usernameController: usernameController);
    final passwordField = PasswordTextField(style: style, passwordController: passwordController);
    final rememberMeCheckbox = Checkbox(
      value: rememberMe,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() {
          rememberMe = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue related to the way `Checkbox` is written, in theory a checkbox could be either "checked", "unchecked" or "negative checked" (with a cross instead of a check), so the `onChanged` method returns `true` if checked, `false` if unchecked and `null` if negative-checked.

Because in theory it could be `null`, you can't just assign `newValue` to `rememberMe` however, your `Checkbox` will never be negative checked because you didn't tell it to, so you can be sure `newValue` will not be `null`, so you could do something like this:

```
rememberMe = newValue == true;
```

This way if `newValue` was null, `null == true` would evaluate to false.

However **there is a better way to do this!**
You can use the null-check operator (`!`) to tell `newValue` that it can never be null:

```
rememberMe = newValue!;
```

this way, if `newValue` was null, we would get an exception, but we already know `newValue` is not null!

Comment: For cases where you have a `bool?` that could be a `null`, you should prefer `newValue ?? false` instead of `newValue == true` since it makes it much clearer that it intends to handle `null`, and boolean comparisons to `true`/`false` are usually a code smell.